# What's the name for a bar connecting two parts for reinforcement?

Tags: brackets

This shelf bracket has an oblique bar connecting the two arms, to make it stronger. That bar makes it a 'Heavy duty shelf bracket'. Does that bar have a name? Like 'reinforcing bar' for example.

I checked the definition of 'crossbar' and it doesn't fit into it because it's not a horizontal bar.

[image: Heavy duty shelf bracket]

Comment: A brace. That is a braced angle with an angle brace.

Comment: It could be referred to as a strut

Answer (score 2):

Another term for this sort of feature is gusset.

[image: gusset image]

Often enough, a gusset is a flat plate engaging both parts at one edge, but it appears that when used with "shelf" the brace reference is translated to gusset. Both terms appear to work well.

[image: gusset with braces]

The image above shows double braces held in place by gussets, although if there were no gussets, the term apparently still applies. Brace is better terminology, though.